# Using another foreign key in limit_choices_to of a foreign key

Tags: python, django

I want to use a foreign key in limit_choices_to, but i am getting an error of

> Cannot resolve keyword u'product_type.product_type' into field. Choices are: id, pantvariation, product_brand, product_brand_id, product_id, product_type, product_type_id, shirtvariation

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=70, choices=choices.PRODUCT_TYPES)
    variation_model_name = models.CharField(max_length=70,blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        temp = ProductType()
        temp.product_type = self.product_type
        temp.variation_model_name = self.product_type.capitalize() + "Variation"
        super(ProductType, temp).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_type


class WarehouseStock(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType)
    product_brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.product_id
class PantVariation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(WarehouseStock, limit_choices_to= {'product_type.product_type': 'pant'})
    size = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices= choices.PANT_SIZES)
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    fit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=choices.FIT_TYPES)
```

I want to use product_type.product_type from WarehouseStock in limit_choices_to, how do i do that?

edit: Full error:

> FieldError at /admin/warehouse/pantvariation/add/
>   Cannot resolve keyword u'product_type.product_type' into field. Choices are: id, pantvariation, product_brand, product_brand_id, product_id, product_type, product_type_id, shirtvariation
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/warehouse/pantvariation/add/
>
> Django Version:   1.9.7
>
> Exception Type:   FieldError
>
> Exception Value:   Cannot resolve keyword u'product_type.product_type'
>   into field. Choices are: id, pantvariation, product_brand,
>   product_brand_id, product_id, product_type, product_type_id,
>   shirtvariation

Comment: can you provide query and line where this error occurs?

Comment: Added more details about the errors.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you cannot make this work easily that way. However, I would restructure your PantVariation model in this way:

```
class PantVariation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, related_name="pants", limit_choices_to= {'product_type.': 'pant'}
```

)

That should work. And you still can access the WarehouseStock model via the ProductType model. Does this do what you want?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't, I want the foriegnkey to be to WarehouseStock so i only see products which are pants. Making the foriegn key to ProductType will let me choose betweeen the product_type not the product_id that has pant type.

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232435/how-do-i-restrict-foreign-keys-choices-to-related-objects-only-in-django ?