# Django Create and Update views: foreign key field

Tags: django, constraints, django-generic-views, generic-foreign-key

Suppose I have the two following classes :

```
class Parcel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
    garden = models.ForeignKey(Garden, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Bed(models.Model):
    parcel = models.ForeignKey(Parcel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm using Django's generic views to Create and Update new beds. As `parcel` is a Foreign Key, Django automatically create a select input with all existing parcels in the database. However, I would like to tell Django to put only parcels with a certain garden_id.
I looked at the function `get_initial(self)`, but I don't want to specify an initial value for the parcel, just narrow the choices of parcels.

If anyone has an idea, it would help me a lot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

Example:

```
staff_member = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True},
)
```

In your case maybe use:

```
limit_choices_to={'garden_id__in': ['list', 'of', 'valid', 'ids']}
```

Source:
[How do I restrict foreign keys choices to related objects only in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232435/how-do-i-restrict-foreign-keys-choices-to-related-objects-only-in-django)