# How to Extend The User Model with field of another class in django?

Tags: django

i want make an extend of the User Model with field 
 from another class (structure in models.py 
 in immob app) in django ,i will show you my project this is my project structure

```
+INVEST_APP
settings.py
urls.py
views.py
wsgi.py
>compte
>immob
>static
>staticfiles
>templates
__init__.py
manage.py
```

and this is my immob model

```
class structure(models.Model):
    structure_code=models.CharField(max_length=1)
    structure_desig=models.CharField(max_length=350)

class service(models.Model):
    structure_id=models.ForeignKey(structure,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)
    service_desig=models.CharField(max_length=350)

class immob(models.Model):
    immo_code=models.CharField(max_length=7)
    immo_desig=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    immo_qte=models.FloatField(default=1)
    immo_datemes=models.DateTimeField()
    immo_cptimmob=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    immo_dureevie=models.IntegerField(default=7)
    immo_numaut=models.CharField(max_length=4)
    immo_origine=models.CharField(max_length=1)
    immo_fournisseur=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    immo_nufact=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    immo_datefact=models.DateTimeField()
    immo_valht=models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    immo_monaie=models.CharField(max_length=3)
    immo_tauxcvt=models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    immo_tauxctrval=models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    immo_frais=models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    immo_coutacq=models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    immo_refcmde=models.CharField(max_length=35)
    immo_datecmde=models.DateField()
    immo_journee=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    immo_cptanal=models.CharField(max_length=9)
    immo_local=models.CharField(max_length=45)
    immo_mode_amort=models.CharField(max_length=1)
    immo_code_r=models.CharField(max_length=2)
    immo_val_amort=models.DecimalField(max_digits=18,decimal_places=2)
    immo_status=models.CharField(max_length=1)
    immo_code_bar=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    service_id=models.ForeignKey(service, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)
```

finaly i want get this in signup.html

```
   username:........
   password:.......
   structure:......
```

(the field structure  is dblookup combobox it means 
i want read it   from database)
 thank you

Comment: Post your models.py and what you are trying to do?

Comment: i have two apps in my project is compte and immob , i poste /immob/models.py and i want extend user model in /compte/modesl.py for using it in signup  because my menu in signup will be like this:                                                                                              username:........                                   password:...................                                                                                           structure :...............                                                                                    submit   return

Comment: Have you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44109/4744341)? I suppose it may contain the information you need.

Comment: i see it but is complicated for me i don't understand it is so difficult i hope have help in my example to understand how i do it because you know is hard work to extend user model

Comment: From `field structure is dblookup combobox it means i want read it from database` it sounds like you might be looking for a `ForeignKey.limit_choices_to`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/252087/1101109

Comment: yes it is like that i will give you and example :                                                  username :Franky                                                                                                    password :azerty                                                                                          structure : electronical departement                                                                       so i want get structure designation in combobox